# QML visualize array data as heatmap on a QML map

Tags: python, plot, geolocation, qml, visualization

First here is the python file:

```
from random import random, randint
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtQuickWidgets, QtPositioning
from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Slot,Signal, Qt, QModelIndex, QCoreApplication, QPointF, QUrl, QByteArray, \
    QTimer
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class MarkerItem(object):
    def __init__(self, position, source):
        self._position = position
        self._source = source

    def position(self):
        return self._position

    def setPosition(self, value):
        self._position = value

    def source(self):
        return self._source

    def setSource(self, value):
        self._source = value


class MarkerModel(QAbstractListModel):
    PositionRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    SourceRole = Qt.UserRole + 2

    _roles = {PositionRole: QByteArray(b"marker_position"), SourceRole: QByteArray(b"type")}

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._markers = []

    def rowCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._markers)

    def roleNames(self):
        return self._roles

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.row() >= self.rowCount():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        marker = self._markers[index.row()]

        if role == MarkerModel.PositionRole:
            return marker.position()

        elif role == MarkerModel.SourceRole:
            return marker.source()

        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            marker = self._markers[index.row()]
            if role == MarkerModel.PositionRole:
                marker.setPosition(value)

            if role == MarkerModel.SourceRole:
                marker.setSource(value)

            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return QAbstractListModel.setData(self, index, value, role)
    
    @Slot(float, float, int)
    def addEntry(self, lat, lon, index):
        coord =  QtPositioning.QGeoCoordinate(lat,lon)
        myitem = MarkerItem(coord, index)
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._markers.append(myitem)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def appendMarker(self, marker):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._markers.append(marker)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return QAbstractListModel.flags(index)|Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def moveRandom(self, ix):
        ind = self.index(ix, 0)
        current_pos = self.data(ind, MarkerModel.PositionRole)
        next_pos = QtPositioning.QGeoCoordinate((current_pos.latitude() +0.002*(random() - 0.5)), (current_pos.longitude() +0.002*(random() - 0.5)))
        self.setData(ind, next_pos, MarkerModel.PositionRole)
       # self.setData(ind, QColor(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)), MarkerModel.ColorRole)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    
    if not QGuiApplication.instance():
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseDesktopOpenGL,True)
        app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QGuiApplication.instance()
 
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    
    model = MarkerModel()
    model.appendMarker(MarkerItem(QtPositioning.QGeoCoordinate(-12.0464, -77.0428),0))
    model.appendMarker(MarkerItem(QtPositioning.QGeoCoordinate(-12.0340, -77.0428), 1))

    model.appendMarker(MarkerItem(QtPositioning.QGeoCoordinate(-12.0440, -77.0280), 2))

    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty('markermodel', model)
   

    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile("main2.qml"))

    if len(engine.rootObjects()) == 0:
        sys.exit(-1)

    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)

    timer = QTimer(engine)
    
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: model.moveRandom(0))
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: model.moveRandom(1))
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: model.moveRandom(2))
    timer.start(100)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This allows me to have a marker model in python which I can use to stream markers to the QML side and visualize them as well as manipulate them (e.g. move them). Here Source allows to switch between different marker images.

The QML side looks as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.5
import QtPositioning 5.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtDataVisualization 1.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id:rectangle
    visible: true
    title: "Python OSM"
    width: 1280
    height: 960

    
    Component {
       id: c1_cmp
       Image{
            ...
         }
     }
    ....
     Component {
       id: c4_cmp
       Image{
            ...
         }
     }
Component {
       id: c5_cmp
       Image{
            ...
         }
     }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "osm"
             PluginParameter{
            name:"osm.mapping.providersrepository.address"
            value: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
        }
        }
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(-27.0464, 153.0428)
        zoomLevel: 14
               MapItemView{
                    model: markermodel
                    delegate: MapQuickItem {
                        id: marker
                        coordinate: model.marker_position
                        sourceItem:   Loader {       
                            sourceComponent: [c1_cmp, c2_cmp, c3_cmp, c4_cmp, c5_cmp] 
      [model.type]
                        }
                           anchorPoint.x: marker.width/2
                           anchorPoint.y: marker.height/2
                    }
                }


                MouseArea
                {
                    id: mouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    onClicked: {
 markermodel.addEntry((map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).latitude), (map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).longitude),bar.currentIndex )
                    }

                }
                
                MapCircle {
    center {
        latitude: -27.5
        longitude: 153.0
    }
    opacity:0.5
    radius: 50000.0
    border.width: 0
    RadialGradient {
            anchors.fill: parent
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "red" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.25; color: "blue" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.35; color: "green" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.65; color: "transparent" }
                
            }
        }
}

                TabBar {
                    id: bar
                    width: 500
                    height:25
                    background: Rectangle{
                        opacity:0
                    }
                    Repeater {
                        model: [qsTr("C1"), qsTr("C2"), qsTr("C3"), qsTr("C4"), qsTr("C5")]
                        TabButton {
                            id: control
                            text: modelData
                            contentItem: Text {
                            text: control.text
                            font: control.font
                            opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                            color: bar.currentIndex ===index ? "#e86254" : "#ededed"
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            elide: Text.ElideRight
                        }
                            width: 100
                            property int roundedEdge: 0 // 0 - no rounded edges, 1 - left side rounded, 2 - right side rounded
                            background: Item
                            {
                                Rectangle {
                                    id:     roundRect
                                    height: 25
                                    width:  100
                                    radius: roundedEdge == 0 ? 0 : 5
                                    color:  "#35383b"
                                }

                                Rectangle {
                                    id:     leftSquareRect
                                    visible: roundedEdge == 2
                                    color:  "#35383b"
                                    height: roundRect.height
                                    width:  roundRect.width - roundRect.radius
                                    anchors.bottom : roundRect.bottom
                                    anchors.left : roundRect.left
                                }

                                Rectangle {
                                    id:     rightSquareRect
                                    visible: roundedEdge == 1
                                    color:  "#35383b"
                                    height: roundRect.height
                                    width:  roundRect.width - roundRect.radius
                                    anchors.bottom : roundRect.bottom
                                    anchors.right : roundRect.right
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    onCountChanged: {
                        for(let i = 0; i < bar.count; i++)
                        {
                            if(i == 0)
                                bar.itemAt(i).roundedEdge = 1
                            else if(i == bar.count - 1)
                                bar.itemAt(i).roundedEdge = 2
                            else
                                bar.itemAt(i).roundedEdge = 0
                        }
                    }
                    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                        if(bar.currentIndex == 2)
                            print("currentIndex changed to", currentIndex)
                           
                    }
                    
                }  
    }
}
```

For now I implemented a map circle to kind of visualize what it should look like. Ultimately I want to have a data array in python which holds kind of the z values which are then used to plot a heat map at a certain position on the map (lat and lon).
I tried to use a Canvas but it was always moving with my view instead of staying at the map coordinates.

How can I realize this visualization and also update the heatmap later on ?

Note: The map circle is just to have a visual idea, it must not be concentric just data from an array !

Comment: No one got an idea ?